# Upload folder files and save to different directories

Tags: php, html

I'm using this code to upload folder files.

```
    <form action="file_transfer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
        <input type="file" name="file_input[]" id="file_input" multiple="" webkitdirectory="">
        <input type='submit' class='btn' id='btn_upload_file' value='UPLOAD' data-loading-text='loading....'/>
    </form>
```

And file_transfer.php

```
$uploads_dir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/awoc_inspection/Images/IMAGES/';
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_FILES['file_input']['name']); $i++){

$tmp_name = $_FILES['file_input']['tmp_name'][$i];
$name = $_FILES['file_input']['name'][$i];

echo $_FILES['file_input']['tmp_name'][$i];
echo $_FILES['file_input']['name'][$i];

echo"<br/>";
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
}
```

It does not show any error but when I go to C:/xampp/htdocs/awoc_inspection/Images/IMAGES/ 
folder there is no image. I don't know why this code can't move uploaded folder files please help me  :(

Comment: move_uploaded_file gives true or false.. check what it returns..

Comment: change your code to move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir/$name);  and try

Comment: make sure the folder is writeable by your apache process. Also I would use a library for filehandling.

Comment: it returns false ! .. i dont know why ?

Comment: chmod 777 that directory where you are moving file

Comment: did you tried printing `$_FILES`, and see what you are actually receiving?

Comment: it does not work in windows 7.

Comment: when I print_r FILES it shows Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 1(1).JPG [1] => 1.JPG ) [type] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) ) Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 1(1).JPG [1] => 1.JPG ) [type] => Array ( [0] => [1] => )

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. I can only imagine a permission problem. Open the properties of your IMAGES folder. Then "Security" -> "Advanced" -> "Effective Access". Select the user your apache is running under (you can check that in services) and then click on "View effective access". Check if the user has write permissions in that folder.

Comment: why is it the type and tmp_name is empty .. ?

Comment: There you go, problem is your files are not getting transferred..

Comment: Is your temporary dir writable to the apache? You can check which dir it is with `php_info()`

Comment: Or you could check the apache error log. There should be a message about the problem.

Comment: try changing/creating(if doesn't exists) your tmp folder, files you are trying to uploads, aren't getting saved in your tmp folder..thats the only issue..

Comment: And always do your homework before putting your question, you are lucky you haven't received down votes..:)

Comment: Scan this dir for additional .ini files(none)... is this what your talking about ?

Comment: how could i make my dir in apache enabled ?

Comment: tmp folder does not exist ..

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt print error cause you didnt ask it to do:

```
echo $_FILES["file"]["error"][$i];
```

The problem might be that your directory doesnt have good permission try chmod 775 or 777
Also do:

```
echo $result = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

to check whether $result is true or false, if false then moving file wasnt done

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `for` condition with:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_FILES['file_input']); $i++) {
   ...
```

Comment: As you pointed out in my (now deleted) answer: the `[$i]` belongs after the `[$name]`, so `sizeof($_FILES['file_input']['name'])` is correct.

Comment: it show an error ! Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\move_folder\home\file_transfer.php on line 5

Comment: that's not really an error, but rather a notice. anyway, it looks strange. what's the code in line 5?

Answer (score 0):

I've overcome own my problem :) .. thank's everyone for your answers ... the only problem why I can't upload pictures it is because the picture that I'm trying to upload is 3mb above and the maximum upload file_size in php is 2mb .

I've changed php.ini to

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```